# MySQL : store a "post_id" in an "image" table at the same time as the creation of the post

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I am creating a small social network where a user can post a post, and he can add an image to that post.

I am using MySQL for the database.
When I want to create a post without an image there is no problem, but when I want to add an image at the same time as I create the post, I have to add in my "images" table an image whose "post_id" field is equal to the id of the post that was created at the same time, so that the correct image is linked to the correct post.

At the moment my code looks like this: (Node JS)

```
exports.createPost = (req, res, next) => {
  let { body, file } = req;
  console.log(body);
  if (file) {
    const sqlInsertImage = `INSERT INTO images (image_url, post_id) VALUES ("${file.filename}", [*MY POST ID THAT DOESN'T EXIST YET*])`;
  db.query(sqlInsertImage, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(404).json({ err });
      throw err;
    }
  });
  }

  delete(req.body.image)
  body = {
    ...body,
    likes: "",
  };

  const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO posts SET ?";
  db.query(sqlInsert, body, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(404).json({ err });
      throw err;
    }
    res.status(200).json({ msg: "Post added..." });
  });
};
```

Basically, if there is an image in the request, before adding the post to my database, I add the image in the image table, but I don't know how to store the correct post_id since the post will be created at the same time.

How can i set the correct post_id in my "post_id" field in my "images" table ?

Answer (score 0):

I have do this and it works but i dont know if it's a good practice to do query in query. (but it works !)

```
exports.createPost = (req, res, next) => {
  let { body, file } = req;
  if (!file) delete req.body.image;
  body = {
    ...body,
    likes: "",
  };
  const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO posts SET ?";
  db.query(sqlInsert, body, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(404).json({ err });
      throw err;
    }
    // post_id will be equal to the post inserted, and will be reused to link the image at the correct post in the below query
    const post_id = result.insertId;
    if (file) {
      const sqlInsertImage = `INSERT INTO images (image_url, post_id) VALUES ("${file.filename}", ${post_id})`;
      db.query(sqlInsertImage, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(404).json({ err });
          throw err;
        }
        res.status(200).json({ msg: "added..." });
      });
    }
  });
};
```